# How to make an accordion with d3 and angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am trying to make an accordion with D3.js and Angular.js. I have taken code from a couple different places and tried to piece it together to get it to work with not much luck. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <accordion></accordion>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('accordionController', function($scope){
//initiate an array to hold all active tabs
$scope.activeTabs = [];
//check if the tab is active
$scope.isOpenTab = function (tab) {
    //check if this tab is already in the activeTabs array
    if ($scope.activeTabs.indexOf(tab) > -1) {
        //if so, return true
        return true;
    } else {
        //if not, return false
        return false;
    }
}

//function to 'open' a tab
$scope.openTab = function (tab) {
    //check if tab is already open
    if ($scope.isOpenTab(tab)) {
        //if it is, remove it from the activeTabs array
        $scope.activeTabs.splice($scope.activeTabs.indexOf(tab), 1);
    } else {
        //if it's not, add it!
        $scope.activeTabs.push(tab);
    }
}
})

app.directive('accordion', function(){
function link(scope, el){
    d3.select(el[0]).append("div")
        .attr('class', 'accordionContainer')
        .attr('ng-controller', "accordionController");

    var accordion = d3.select(".accordionContainer");

    for (var i = 1; i <=5; i++) {
        var accordionTab = accordion.append("div")
            .attr('class', 'accordionTab');

        accordionTab.append("div")
            .attr('class', 'accordionTabTitle')
            .attr('ng-click', "openTab('tab " + i + "')")
            .text("Tab " + i);

        accordionTab.append("div")
            .attr('class', 'accordionTabContent')
            .attr('ng-click', "isOpenTab('tab " + i + "')")
            .text("Tab " + i + " content goes here!");
    }

}

return {
    link:link,
    restrict: 'E'
}
})
```

I am fairly new to D3 and completely new to Angular. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, why use d3 here?

Comment: I thought it would be a good way to dynamically make the accordion so that it can be as big or as small as you want. Is there a better way?

Comment: Certainly can use it, but unless you are going to use the SVG capabilities of D3 then you should probably just stick to jQuery/jqlite

Comment: d3 makes little sense for this, an accordion is basic DOM manipulation